# IntelliJ IDEA do not show injected dependencies when using @Resource

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA do not show spring injected dependencies when using @Resource:

```
@Resouce
List<People> people;
```

Idea can not navigate to dependencyies when using @Resource,but if use @Autowired,it works!
How make @Resource works as @Autowired?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `@Resource` annotation, you can specify the `name` attribute of the annotation and then the IntelliJ navigation works again:

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldRestController {

  // navigatable 
  @Resource(name = "httpServletRequest")
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  // not-navigatable 
  @Resource
  private HttpServletRequest request1;

  // ... more

}
```

[image]